# Long.getLong() failing, returning null to valid string

Tags: android, string, nullpointerexception, long-integer, string-parsing

I've spent the past two hours debugging what seems extremely unlikely.  I've stripped the method of a secondary Android Activity to exactly this:

```
public void onClick(View v) {
        String str = "25";
        long my_long = Long.getLong(str);
} // onClick (v)
```

And yeah, I get a crash with the good ol' NullPointerException:

09-11 02:02:50.444: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1588): Uncaught handler: thread main exiting due to uncaught exception
09-11 02:02:50.464: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1588): java.lang.NullPointerException

It looks like (from other tests) that Long.getLong(str) returns NULL, which is driving me bonkers.  WHAT AM I MISSING?

Thanks in advance.  I'm okay with stupidly missing the obvious, but my sanity is on the line.

Comment: use Long.parseLong(str); instead of Long.getLong(str);

Answer (score 123, accepted):

You are missing the fact that `Long.getLong(String str)` is not supposed to parse a String to a long, but rather to return a long value of a **system property** represented by that string. As others have suggested, what you actually need is `Long.parseLong(String str)`.

Comment: I have often wondered what `getLong` and the other getX of the primitive types where supposed to do. It seems to me to be a very poor design choice to have `getLong` on the `Long` class which is related to system variables or perhaps just a curse to those of us who, like my self, use ctrl+space too extensively. Great response.

Answer (score 12):

You can use `Long.parseLong(String)`, instead of `getLong(String)`: it will solve the problem.

Answer (score 7):

I think you are using wrong function use **Long.parseLong(str)** then you can get the right answer.

Answer (score 7):

Long.parseLong(someString) approved. Don't forget to catch NumberFormatException if there's a probability of unparsable string.

Answer (score 6):

To understand this, some examples:

```
Long val= Long.getLong("32340");
```

returns: `null`

```
Long val = Long.getLong("32340", 3000);
```

returns: `3000`

Using **[Long.parseLong()](http://developer.android.com/intl/es/reference/java/lang/Long.html#parseLong(java.lang.String))** :

```
Long val  = Long.parseLong("32340");
```

returns: `32340`

The documentation describe [getLong()](http://developer.android.com/intl/es/reference/java/lang/Long.html#getLong(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Long)) method as :

> Returns the Long value of the **system property** identified by string.

this is the code of the **getLong()** method and only get a property value defined by a string:

```
  public static Long getLong(String string) {
        if (string == null || string.length() == 0) {
            return null;
        }
        String prop = System.getProperty(string);
        if (prop == null) {
            return null;
        }
        try {
            return decode(prop);
        } catch (NumberFormatException ex) {
            return null;
        }
    }
```

#### If you want to parse a String to Long, the best way is using **[Long.parseLong()](http://developer.android.com/intl/es/reference/java/lang/Long.html#parseLong(java.lang.String))** method.

Answer (score 2):

You can use Long.parseLong(String), instead of getLong(String): it will solve the problem.