# pass a array in querybuilder in statement

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I am using a query builder to  create a query statement in hibernate. i need to pass a arrayList for in statement. How can this be done.
Dummy code :

```
List<String> xyz = new ArrayList<String>("sam","tam","vam");
StringBuilder queryBuilder = new StringBuilder("select abc from tem where xyz in :xyzList");
Query query = entityManager.createNativeQuery(queryBuilder.toString());
query.setParameter("xyzList", xyz);
query.getResultList();
```

this is not working. it throws exceptions. Can somebody point me how to do this.

Comment: What kind of exceptions does it throw? Could you please provide a Stacktrace?

Comment: This is probably what you want: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3126366/doing-an-in-query-with-hibernate

Answer (score 0):

Use `setParameterList("xyzList", new String []{"a","b","c"});`

So if you have the list with you, you can do `list.toArray()` in place of new `String []{"a","b","c"}`

Comment: `setParameterList()` is not available in `javax.persistence.Query`, which the OP is using since the query is created with `entityManager.createNativeQuery()`. That is a method of `org.hibernateQuery`.

Answer (score 0):

You have seemed to be mistaken an `entityManager.createNativeQuery` with `entityManager.createNamedQuery` or `entityManager.createQuery`

The syntax of your query is JPQL, but you compile it as a native query syntax

What should work for you is to move from `createNativeQuery` simply to `createQuery`, or align it the other way around so write a proper native query if that is your goal.

Note just that if you're intent was to go for a native query you should stay away from the named parameters. In your case it would work since you're using hibernate as persistence provider, but otherwise, named parameters in native queries are not supported according to JPA specification