# Hibernate ProjectionList for getting count from table with column value restrictions

Tags: java, hibernate, projection

```
class Books{
    private int bookId; //primary key
    private String bookName;
    Private String category;
}
```

Consider the above model class(Books) where it has category variable as A,B,C.

It is stored in table - 'books' with column names 'book_id' ,'book_name' , 'category'(category values will be either A or B or C).

Using **Hibernate ProjectionList**, I would like to have

```
1.count of book_id(from DB table) with category value as A 
2.count of book_id(from DB table) with category value as B 
3.count of book_id(from DB table) with category value as C
```

Assign it to a 3 separate int values countA,countB,countC

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do we count rows using Hibernate?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1372317/how-do-we-count-rows-using-hibernate)

Comment: @MichaelDibbets Your link answers projection count of entire table not with restrictions

Comment: check the second answer... or the third, or the fourth or the fifth...

Comment: @MichaelDibbets I dont find any restrictions involvement there. Don't find solution for my asked question.

Comment: What if you use native query and get sum of all categories using `GROUP BY`?

Answer (score 0):

Just to show one of the methods to do it, als linked in [How do we count rows using Hibernate?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1372317/how-do-we-count-rows-using-hibernate) combined with 
[Doing an "IN" query with Hibernate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3126366/doing-an-in-query-with-hibernate)

```
Integer count = (Integer) session.CreateQuery("select count(*) from Books where category = ?1")
     .query.setParameter(1, "A")
     .uniqueResult();
```

Comment: your answer gives me total count. I want it as a separate count @MichaelDibbets

Comment: Are you really expecting to be spoon fed?? This is all the help i'm giving. learn how to build queries for christs sake.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28829818/how-to-create-a-native-query-with-named-parameters

Comment: I know it, look at my edited answer, but this is like the first thing you see if you'd read the documentation... Where queries, selecing counts, etc.

Comment: Find my answer below @MichaelDibbets

Answer (score 0):

```
                Criteria cr = session.createCriteria(Book.class);
                ProjectionList projList = Projections.projectionList();        
                projList.add(Projections.groupProperty("category"));
                projList.add(Projections.count("category").as("count"));
                cr.setProjection(projList);
                List<Object[]> rows = cr.list();
                if(rows.size()>0){
                    for(Object[] itr : rows){
                        if("A".equalsIgnoreCase(((String) itr[0]).trim())){
                            int countA = (long)itr[1];
                        }
                        if("B".equalsIgnoreCase(((String) itr[0]).trim())){
                            int countB = (long)itr[1];
                        }
                        if("C".equalsIgnoreCase(((String) itr[0]).trim())){
                            int countC = (long)itr[1];
                        }
                    }
                }
```