# Query with a list of embedded primary keys

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate

I'm trying to query for a list of objects using a list of embedded primary keys. Something like this:

User.java

```
public class User {
   @EmbeddedId
   protected UserPK userPK;

   //getter & setters...
}
```

UserPK.java

```
@Embeddable
public class UserPK {
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "group")
    private String group;

    //getter & setters...
}
```

UserDao.java

```
public List<Long> getUsersById(List<UserPK> ids) {
    TypedQuery<User> q = entityManager.createQuery(
        "SELECT u FROM User AS u WHERE u.userPK IN :ids", User.class);
    q.setParameter("ids", ids);
    return q.getResultList();
}
```

Basically, I'm querying for multiple users, lets say:

id=1 group="it"
id=2 group="eng"

How can I query Users with a list of composite primary keys?

Comment: possible duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3126366/doing-an-in-query-with-hibernate  but there again hard to know unless you ask a question

Comment: Yea I'm aware of using IN for single fields, but not embedded objects. In this case the primary key is a composite key, so I'm not sure to build this query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you did is totally fine, although there is a minor correction needed on the return type of `getUsersById` method, which should be `List<User>` instead of `List<Long>`.

You can query using a list of UserPKs objects and use that as a parameter to your IN operator. So the query below (like you did) will work fine:

```
public List<User> getUsersByIdCombo(List<UserPK> ids) {
    TypedQuery<User> q = entityManager.createQuery("SELECT u FROM User AS u WHERE u.userPK IN :ids", User.class);
    q.setParameter("ids", ids);
    return q.getResultList();
}
```

You can also query by traversing the embedded id class explicitly (`userPK.id` or `userPK.group`). Here are samples below:

```
public List<User> getUsersById(List<Long> ids) {
    TypedQuery<User> q = entityManager.createQuery("SELECT u FROM User AS u WHERE u.userPK.id IN :ids", User.class);
    q.setParameter("ids", ids);
    return q.getResultList();
}

public List<User> getUsersByGroup(List<String> groups) {
    TypedQuery<User> q = entityManager.createQuery("SELECT u FROM User AS u WHERE u.userPK.group IN :groups", User.class);
    q.setParameter("groups", groups);
    return q.getResultList();
}

public User getSingleUserByIdAndGroup(Long id, String group) {
    TypedQuery<User> q = entityManager.createQuery("SELECT u FROM User AS u WHERE u.userPK.id = :id AND u.userPK.group = :group", User.class);
    q.setParameter("id", id);
    q.setParameter("group", group);
    return q.getSingleResult();
}
```

Let's see how these queries behave by testing each method. Let's say we have this data on your `USER` table.

[image]

**Example 1: Query users by list of UserPK objects**

```
    List<UserPK> userPKs = new ArrayList<UserPK>();
    userPKs.add(new UserPK(1L, "it"));
    userPKs.add(new UserPK(4L, "eng"));
    List<User> userListQuery1 = userDAO.getUsersByIdCombo(userPKs);
    for (User user: userListQuery1) {
        System.out.println(user);
    }
```

Result:

```
ID: 4 | GROUP: eng
ID: 1 | GROUP: it
```

**Example 2: Query users by List of ids**

```
    List<Long> ids = new ArrayList<Long>();
    ids.add(2L);
    ids.add(5L);
    List<User> userListQuery2 = userDAO.getUsersById(ids);
    for (User user: userListQuery2) {
        System.out.println(user);
    }
```

Result:

```
ID: 5 | GROUP: eng
ID: 2 | GROUP: it
```

**Example 3: Query users by list of groups**

```
    List<String> groups = new ArrayList<String>();
    groups.add("it");
    groups.add("eng");
    List<User> userListQuery3 = userDAO.getUsersByGroup(groups);
    for (User user: userListQuery3) {
        System.out.println(user);
    }
```

Result:

```
ID: 4 | GROUP: eng
ID: 5 | GROUP: eng
ID: 1 | GROUP: it
ID: 2 | GROUP: it
```

**Example 4: Query single user by id and by group**

```
    User user = userDAO.getSingleUserByIdAndGroup(3L, "hr");
    System.out.println(user);
```

Result:

```
ID: 3 | GROUP: hr
```

Comment: You can see a sample code from here:
https://github.com/balagueri21/sample-codes/tree/master/QueryCompositePrimaryKeys

Comment: Thank you, appreciate the detailed answer.