# How to use the IN clause while using EntityManager with Hibernate

Tags: sql, hibernate, sqlparameter, sql-in

How do I exactly write the following query using entityManager.

```
Select * from TABLE_NAME where column_name in ('A', 'B');
```

I tried with the `setParametrList()` method. However, it says that this method is not available for type Query.

```
Query query = entityManager.createQuery(
                "Select t from  TableEntity t WHERE t.name =:bd AND t.staus in (:statuses)", TableEntity .class)
                .setParameter("bd", bd)
                .setParameterList("statuses", statuses);

Error: The method setParameterList(String, List<String>) is undefined for the type TypedQuery<TableEntity >
```

The same method seems to work fine while using `session.createQuery`. Any suggestions on this.

Comment: Related: [Doing an “IN” query with Hibernate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3126366/doing-an-in-query-with-hibernate)

Answer (score 2):

Just use `setParameter("statuses", statuses)` with the list. The method checks if the parameter is a collection and expands it.

Comment: Also by JPA standard, the syntax is `t.staus in :statuses`, but I'm fairly certain Hibernate allows `t.staus in (:statuses)`